# Get closest date with id and value Oracle

Tags: oracle

I ran into a problem and maybe there are experienced guys here to help me figure it out:
I have a table with rows:

| ID | VALUE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2827 | 0 | 20.07.2022 10:40:01 |
| 490 | 27432 | 20.07.2022 10:40:01 |
| 565 | 189 | 20.07.2022 9:51:03 |
| 200 | 1 | 20.07.2022 9:50:01 |
| 731 | 0.91 | 20.07.2022 9:43:21 |
| 161 | 13004 | 19.07.2022 16:11:01 |

This table has a million records, there are about 1000 ID instances, only the date of the value change and, therefore, the value itself changes in them.
When the value of the ID changes is added to this table:

**ID |  Tme the value was changed (DATE) | VALUE**

My task is to get the all id's values closest to the input date.

I mean: if I input date "20.07.2022 10:00:00"
I want to get each ID (1-1000) with rows "value, date" with last date before "20.07.2022 10:00:00":

| ID | VALUE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2827 | 0 | 20.07.2022 9:59:11 |
| 490 | 27432 | 20.07.2022 9:40:01 |
| 565 | 189 | 20.07.2022 9:51:03 |
| 200 | 1 | 20.07.2022 9:50:01 |
| 731 | 0.91 | 20.07.2022 8:43:21 |
| 161 | 13004 | 19.07.2022 16:11:01 |

What query will be the most optimal and correct in this case?

Comment: What is desired result (based on data you posted as example)?

Comment: @Littlefoot I need a query which consist ID, DT, VALUE of each unique ID where DT is close to the input date. It is desirable that the request takes about 5 seconds. I was able to implement a request that takes 15 seconds

Comment: Please post your sample data and expected result for that data and an example input date as formatted text (not an image). You also need to clarify what 'closest' means to you - the last date before your input date, or the smallest gap to a date either before or after (and which to choose if there is a tie).

Comment: @AlexPoole edited the text for your questions. Yes, by "closest" I means the last date before your input date

Comment: Your new data and result doesn't really show what's happening. Your sample has no value for ID 2827 before 10:00; it really needs to show multiple values for each ID, before and after your example input date? I think I understand what you mean though, so I've posted my answer based on your previous data - it would still be helpful to have meaningful data in the question though (if only to check I've understood properly...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data for each ID with the latest change up to, but not after, your input date then you can just filter on that date, and use aggregate functions to get the most recent data in that filtered range:

```
select id,
  max(change_time) as change_time,
  max(value) keep (dense_rank last order by change_time) as value
from your_table
where change_time <= <your input date>
group by id
```

With your previous sample data, using midnight this morning as the input date would give:

```
select id,
  max(change_time) as change_time,
  max(value) keep (dense_rank last order by change_time) as value
from your_table
where change_time <= timestamp '2022-07-28 00:00:00'
group by id
order by id
```

| ID | CHANGE_TIME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-24 10:00:00 | 900 |
| 2 | 2022-07-22 21:51:00 | 422 |
| 3 | 2022-07-24 13:01:00 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-07-24 10:48:00 | 67 |

and using midday today woudl give:

```
select id,
  max(change_time) as change_time,
  max(value) keep (dense_rank last order by change_time) as value
from your_table
where change_time <= timestamp '2022-07-28 12:00:00'
group by id
order by id
```

| ID | CHANGE_TIME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-24 10:00:00 | 900 |
| 2 | 2022-07-22 21:51:00 | 422 |
| 3 | 2022-07-28 11:59:00 | 12 |
| 4 | 2022-07-28 11:45:00 | 63 |
| 5 | 2022-07-28 10:20:00 | 55 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8bca4d579555c7ffdd2f85faf75e4e10) with some other input dates to show the result set changing.